# Estimation of the Vech HAR model (Multivariate HAR)

Tags: volatility, estimation, multivariate

I am trying to use the Vech-HAR (the mulitvariate HAR) model in order to forecast some covariances.
I have been looking into the model proposed by Chiriac *Modelling and forecasting multivariate realized volatility* (2010) ([link](http://public.econ.duke.edu/%7Eget/browse/courses/201/spr12/DOWNLOADS/VolatilityMeasures/SpecificlPapers/chiriac_voev_jae_10.pdf)) that states the model as:
[image]

Here $X_t = vech(P_t)$ where $P_t$ comes from the cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix Y such that $Y_t = P_t'P_t$.
My question is, how can this easily be estimated by OLS?
First of all as I see it, $X_t$ is a time dependent vector at time t consisting of covariance inputs. So in some sense this could actually also be seen as a matrix that has the covariance inputs in on dimension and time as the second dimension, right? How can I regress this $X^{(d)}$, $X^{(w)}$ and $X^{(m)}$ which as I see it could also be seen as matrices?
Furthermore, how can I make sure that all the betas are scalars and not vectors like c?